# Tagging an arbitrary value with metadata in Python

Tags: python

I've devised an evil scheme to add tags to Python objects via inheritance the following way:

```
def tag(val, tag_cls):
    val_cls = type(val)
    class tagged_cls(val_cls, tag_cls):
        pass
    tagged_cls.__name__ = '{}({})'.format(tag_cls.__name__, val_cls.__name__)
    return tagged_cls(val)

# Example tags
class Foo: pass
class Bar: pass

def foo(val): return tag(val, Foo)
def bar(val): return tag(val, Bar)
```

So then I can wrap values with these and they will behave exactly like original values when comparing, but will have extra info on them.

```
>>> k = foo('key')
>>> k
'key'
>>> k == 'key'
True
>>> {'key': 'value'}[k]
'value'
>>> isinstance(k, Foo)
True
>>> isinstance(k, Bar)
False
```

The above works, but I feel like this is a bit too clever and *surely* there is a more pythonic way to do it.

Any better way? Anything immediately wrong with the above approach?

Comment: Sounds XYish. What do you need it for?

Comment: @CatPlusPlus, I'm writing something similar to this https://github.com/alecthomas/voluptuous but trying to simplify dict matching logic (the lib linked has to double-iterate over schema keys and data keys because they are not comparable).